# iOS CNContat : Contact's authorization status in today extension is different to main app's

Tags: ios, authorization, cncontact, cncontactstore

I have developed a today extension using Contacts framework.
After allowing to access contacts in the main app (I touched down "OK" button on a alert that explaining "ABC app" would like to access your contacts), I checked CNAuthorizationStatus is CNAuthorizationStatusAuthorized.
But, when I logged the status on today extension, the value is CNAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined.
Why this problem is occurred? And how can I fix it?